# ¿como identificar problemas de rendimiento/bloqueo de una web api en Net. Core?

Tags: sql-server, angular, archivo, asp.net-core, rendimiento

resulta que tengo una backend hecho con .net core 2.2, un frontend hecho en angular 7 y una base de datos en sql server, puesto en producción, desde hace unas semanas al estar usando la aplicación se queda procesando varios minutos el backend o incluso hemos llegado a tener que reiniciar el servicio desde el IIS, hemos hecho varios cambios como: agregar indices a las tablas, agregar llaves de foraneas, liberar el log de base de datos, aumentar memoria ram a los servidores, aumentar procesadores, cambiar a métodos asíncronos, pero no notamos que haya mejorado, incluso creemos que ha empeorado. ya hemos monitoreado los recursos de los servidores sin embargo no hemos identificado cuales son los problemas que causan el bloqueo.

Mi pregunta aquí es: ¿que herramientas, estrategia, etc me recomiendan usar para monitorear el rendimiento de las aplicaciones y base de datos o algo que me recomienden cambiar a la base de datos o código?

adiccional:

1. la aplicación cuenta con métodos para copiar archivos de una directorio a otro
2. el backend consume tres servicios WCF
3. la concurrecia es de 100 usuario aproximadamente
4. los servidores son virtuales
5. los servidores cuentan con windows server 2012, 48 RAM 4 procesadores

De antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

No soy amante de Windows, pero intento responder con cosas genéricas para que vayas viendo. Tampoco soy muy bueno expresandome y tal vez, se me escapa el sarcasmo. Perdón de antemano, ante la duda, interpretá para bien.

---

No es muy fácil recomendar tocar el código o la base, sin conocer la estructura de la db o el código.

Si no estás monitoreando permanentemente con algún sistema de monitoreo (zabbix, nagios, check_mk, otros), no estás monitoreando; estás jugando a "a ver a qué pasa si toco acá". Lo que no se mide, no se puede mejorar.

1- He visto atrocidades, como más de 8.000.000 de archivos en un solo directorio. Si es así, chequea la documentación del sistema operativo para conocer el límite. Organiza por directorios.

2 - ¿El tiempo de respuesta es aceptable?. Revisa ancho de banda, y en lo posible, resolución de DNS

3 - 1, 10, 100 o mil. Lo que importa, es lo de adentro. ¿Puede el servidor manejarlos? ¿Qué pruebas de stress testing hiciste?

4 - Hmmm.. podría (tentativamente) no tener mucho que ver. Revisa el punto 1, necesitas monitorear realmente. El problema podría estar en cualquier lado, en el firewall.. IIS, el sistema operativo, la base o los recursos externos, la VM o el físico.

5 - Puede ser mucho, puede ser poco.. lo dirá el monitoreo ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Revisa si no estás recibiendo trafico inusual o sospechoso en los servidores web.
Revisa si la base de datos está tardando mucho en responder (los motores de DB suelen tener documentación sobre profiling, o simplemente *explain*). Revisa tambien el tiempo promedio en entregar el resultado (monitoreo, de nuevo)

Comment: Recomendación: es mejor no responder a preguntas basadas en opiniones pues terminan cerradas, lleva 3 de 5 votos